# How to solve- call to a member function save() on a non-object in cake php?

Tags: cakephp, xampp

In the application i am developing, I have created a form in view.ctp file as:

```
<?php
echo $form->create('Answer',array('action'=>'addanswer'));
echo $form->input('ques',array('value'=>'1'));
$userInfo=$this->Session->read('Auth.User');
$user=$userInfo['id'];
echo $form->input('user',array( 'value'=>$user));
echo $form->input('answer');

echo $form->end('Submit answer');
?>
```

And in the answers_controllers.php file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
class AnswersController extends AppController{
    var $name= 'Answers';
    var $uses = array('User');

    function addanswer(){
        if(!empty ($this->data)){
            echo $this->data;
            if($this->Answer->save($this->data)){

                $this->Session->setFlash('The answer has been addedd successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('The answer was not saved. Please re enter the details');
            }
        }
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Add a new Answer');
    }
}
?>
```

But when I press the submit answer button (which is mentioned in view.ctp), i get Call to a member function save() on a non-object.
A code very similar to this one worked perfectly but this is not working.

I am new to cake php, so any help regarding how to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

dont use

```
 var $uses = array('User');
```

! otherwise you are "destroying" the real controller model (which in this case is probably `Answer`).

your Answer model should have a relation to the user anyway via $belongsTo.
Therefore you can still access the User object via

```
$this->Answer->User->...
```